# How to read user phone book contacts without using any plugin or package

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my enterprise application need to read user phone book contacts and save into my database. I have searched more but all are suggest, need to install xamarin.mobile package or plugin. In my application have only limited size, so difficult to install package or plugin. Please suggest any idea to read contacts. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need dependency service to be able to do that.

for more information on how to create a dependency service:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/

You'll need to do this on each platform separately.
How to do it for android: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/contentproviders/read_contacts/

For IOS u can also find on the Xamarin website. But I can't post 2 links

Good luck!

Comment: And this is exactly what plugins do :-)

Comment: Yes indeed but he wants to do it himself if i'm not misunderstanding his question?

Comment: Yes, with hope that doing himself will save application size. My point that it probably will not